# WPF Radio button does not show in toolbar

Tags: wpf, radio-button, toolbar

Is there any way to force a radio button or check box to show properly in a toolbar?  The circle/check box always disappears once its placed inside a toolbar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, WPF overrides RadioButtons to make them look like toggle buttons. To eliminate this, place a panel inside the ToolBar and then put your RadioButton(s) in there.

```
<ToolBar>
   <StackPanel>
      <RadioButton Content="Radio Button" />
   </StackPanel>
</ToolBar>
```